# Apachesolr filter file attachments

Tags: 6, search

Apachesolr search and attachments ver. 6.x-1.x

Apachedolr by default has filters for node content types.  However, there are no filters for file attachments attached to nodes. Furthermore, the  node content type filters do not filter file attachments, even if they are attached to nodes that match the filter.  So, if you execute a search, and receive results with file attachments, there is no way to filter the results to receive all nodes and file attachments within one node content type.

Is it possible to create a content type filter for both nodes and file attachment documents? If so, how?

Comment: Following the guidance here: http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/filtering-apache-solr-search-results-based-on-dynamic-fields/ I am now able to create a filter using hook_apachesolr_modify_query that will return results for both nodes and file attachments.

Comment: Question and answer have been modified according to Stackexchange requirements.  Answer now contains sample code.